# Why does my Gitlab pipeline fail if someone else runs a plan between me doing a build and actually applying my own plan?

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I Tried to run a manual apply (i.e plan) of a pipeline that I had run  a build for a few days earlier. But the manual apply failed...it said this

[image]

I'm pretty sure that this happened because I originally ran a build...then someone else created a build for the same repo and then applied it  in the time between me running the build and actually doing a manual apply....So I think there were 2 plans....but I still can't get in my head what had changed to the plan in the meantime to make my dependency lock file inconsistent..

can anybody help? I hope I've explained myself clearly

ci file is like this

```
image:
  name: $<redacted>

variables:
  PLAN: plan.tfplan

cache:
  paths:
    - .terraform

before_script:
  - export <redacted>
  - export <redacted>
  - export <redacted>
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init -upgrade

stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply
  - destroy

validate:
  stage: validate
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
    - main
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out=$PLAN
    - echo \`\`\`diff > plan.txt
    - terraform show -no-color ${PLAN} | tee -a plan.txt
    - echo \`\`\` >> plan.txt
    - sed -i -e 's/  +/+/g' plan.txt
    - sed -i -e 's/  ~/~/g' plan.txt
    - sed -i -e 's/  -/-/g' plan.txt
    - MESSAGE=$(cat plan.txt)
    - >-
      curl -X POST -g -H <token stuff>
      --data-urlencode "body=${MESSAGE}" 
      "$<ci url project stuff>"
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - $PLAN
  only:
    - merge_requests

build:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out=$PLAN
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - $PLAN
  only:
    - branches

.apply-template:
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false $PLAN

Manual Apply:
  extends: .apply-template
  stage: apply
  dependencies:
    - build
  when: manual
  except:
    - schedules
  only:
    - master
    - main

Scheduled Apply:
  extends: .apply-template
  stage: apply
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - schedules
    
destroy:
  stage: destroy
  script:
    - terraform destroy -auto-approve
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
    - main
```

Comment: We would need to see the associated stages to assist further, but there are various situations you have to account for in pipeline code across all platforms (Jenkins, Circle, GH actions, Travis, Concourse, etc.) if you want to preserve a plan from a PR/MR for the post-approval and merge, and this is one of them.

Comment: @MattSchuchard  hi thanks for this...but can you be more specific about what you mean when you say the "associated stages" please

Comment: I assume you have `plan` and `apply` stages in the GitlabCI config.

Comment: @MattSchuchard  Hi..I've posted the ci file...does this tell you anything about why I might have got this dependency lock file error?

Comment: Now it appears more like a caching issue where the providers were upgraded beyond the lock file associated with the cache due to the `-upgrade` argument. Also, you are hopefully not committing the lock file to the git repo and also executing the `-upgrade`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard  hi ..makes sense now..thanks for that...also repos are secure..but thanks for asking

Comment: Unsure how secure repos are relevant, but if you add an `init` stage and deal with the lock file problem, then that would probably fix your issue.